# jQueryのshowメソッドでアニメーション表示する際、効果を右下から左上へ波及させることは出来る？

Tags: jquery

**jQueryのshowメソッド引数でduration指定することにより、アニメーション表示させたいのですが、この時、アニメーション効果の方向を右下から左上へ設定することはできるでしょうか？**
・対象要素をゆっくりと表示させる際、右下から左上へ向けて徐々に表示させたいのですが…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

showだとできないです。
上から下へだとslideDownでいけますが、
右下から左上へだとanimateでやるしかないですかね。

Comment: なるほど、出来ないんですね。「上下」が出来るなら「斜め」も指定出来るかも、思い質問したのですが…。animateを試してみます